# Python exercise about basics types, functions and plus them, changing the type of input

Tags: python, string, function, types, integer

my python teacher ask to me to write a program that adds the digits in a 2 digit number. e.g. if the input was 35, then the output should be 3 + 5 = 8. So, a made it on this way:

```py
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")
print(int(two_digit_number [0] ) + int(two_digit_number [1]))
```

Is it wrong?

Comment: what do you get as output when you run that script?

Comment: It's working fine but you may want to rethink your design if possible. For ex. the user needs to enter a single number, like "12", and gets back "3" as an output. But based on the problem statement above, looks like that means it's actually "working as intended".

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct but I feel like this is a better way:

```
number = int(input())
print(number // 10 + number % 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine and nothing wrong with it, but if you wanted to you could simplify it a little using builtins like `sum` and `map`. For instance, what `map` does is apply the first callable argument to an iterable passed in as the second argument (a string of characters in this case).

Here's an example using both those builtins. I also use `assert` to confirm once that it's a valid two digit number, because otherwise it'll work for any length number, like a five digit number.

```py
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")

assert len(two_digit_number) == 2, 'Enter a valid two digit number!'

print(sum(map(int, two_digit_number)))
```

If you wanted to, you could also rewrite it like this, using `map` and an assignment using implicit iterable unpacking:

```py
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")

first_dig, second_dig = map(int, two_digit_number)

print(first_dig + second_dig)
```

Answer (score -1):

two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")

first_digit = two_digit_number[0]

second_digit = two_digit_number [1]

result = int(first_digit) + int(second_digit)

print(result)